# Function name in sh

Tags: linux, sh

I am trying to extract the current running function name to generate logs for assertion. here is what i have tried

```
function_name()
 {
   s=${FUNCNAME[0]}
   touch ${s}
 }
```

I think the ${FUNCNAME[0]} only works in bash not in sh.

Is there any way to get the current running function name in sh

Comment: As far as I know, this is not something you can get from POSIX shell.

Comment: you can try preprocess your sh script with awk, to parse functions and inject logging expressions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to insert the logging expressions manually into every function, that's tedious but it can be automated with awk.

Assume you obey the coding conventions you used in the question:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk    
/^[ \t]*function[ \t]*[a-zA-Z_][^(]*\(\)/ {
    name=$0
    sub(/^[ \t]*function[ \t]*/, "", name)
    sub(/[ \t]*\(\).*/, "", name)
    if ($0 !~ /\{/) {
        print
        getline
    }
    print
    print "    s='" name "'"
    print "    touch ${s}"
    next
}
1
```

The code is self-explanatory, for each function in the sh script, it parses the function name, and insert the logging code below. Note the last line in the above code, which means print out all the other lines.